# Android malware ads

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I have developed a hybrid android application where in I am loading my website urls in my application. To introduce recommendation based on users url history, I used to send all the browsing history done in my application to server. But lately when I was checking that I found unusual urls which should not have been present in my server. They are sent by the application but not opened by it. I asked one of my users also that whether he is facing any problems because I was not able to replicate the same issue on my device.

The urls are basically ad related urls which are coming in the history. How is possible that these urls are coming in my history and if they are opening in the application then how is it possible that these urls are opening in my application.

Comment: probably one of your libraries infected your app

Comment: but not everyone is facing this issue. Also I am using libraries of facebook, picasso, viewpager, testing agent. Can anyone of these effect it.

Comment: How are you collecting the browsing history, through an API call or your own application code?  Please paste relevant snippets if you can.